# Kahan algorithm in c++

Tags: c++, random, double, rounding, precision

I have written follwoing kahan algorithm; it reasonably work for n to be from 1 million up to 10 million, but it produces very large error when n is 100 million. I tested it multiple times but I cannot figure out why this is happening.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <random>
#include <cfloat>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;
float KahanAlgorithm(const vector<float> &myarray){
    float sum{0.0f};
    float ac{0.0f};

    for(unsigned int i=0; i<myarray.size();i++){
        float temp{sum+myarray[i]};
        if(sum>=myarray[i]){
            ac=ac+(sum-temp)+myarray[i];
        }
        else{
            ac=ac+(myarray[i]-temp)+sum;
        }
        sum=temp;
    }

    return sum+ac;
}
int main() {

    int n=100000000;
    random_device r;
    default_random_engine g(r());
    uniform_real_distribution<float> d(0.f, nextafter(1.f, DBL_MAX));

    vector<float> a(n);
    vector<double> b(n);

    for(auto i=0;i<n;i++){
        a[i]=d(g);
        b[i]=static_cast<double> (a[i]);

    }

    double exact_sum;
    float kahan_sum;

    exact_sum=accumulate(b.begin(),b.end(),0.0);
    cout<<"exact "<<exact_sum<<endl;
    kahan_sum=KahanAlgorithm(a);
    cout<<" Kahan sum "<<kahan_sum<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

sum is :

```
exact 5.00045e+07
Kahan sum 3.35544e+07
```

Comment: Where did you copy that from? It doesn't match the version on wikipedia (parentheses).

Comment: @Marc Glisse yes, it does  not match, but if it is was wrong, it would also lead to inaccurate results for 10 million as well

Comment: Think of what happens once sum is large enough that adding the next number does not modify it anymore. Then you are simply accumulating to ac. Once that one saturates as well (notice how its value is the same as sum in the end), nothing happens anymore, no matter how many numbers you add.

Comment: @MAero2020: Umm...why do you believe the result from `std::accumulate` is "exact"? Every implementation I've seen just uses a naive summation. The whole reason Kahan summation was invented is because under some circumstances, that produces bad results.

Comment: @JerryCoffin He is using double, compared to float in the other version, so while it may not be exact, it is still more precision than he can get with a pair of float.

Comment: @JerryCoffin I do not believe this is exact and I do not expect exact results! but I also do not expect such a huge error

Comment: @MarcGlisse: oops--I didn't notice it using `double` instead of `float`.

Comment: @JerryCoffin you mentioned `std::accumulate`. when I use this, it leads to 1.67772e+07; it is just too much out of range, but when I use `reduce`, it is acceptable. it really buffers me

Comment: @MarcGlisse it is not the point! I am using double to get this sum as reference. Again, I implement float to see the result of sum and compare. Yes, they should not match at all! it will have error. The thing is not this much error

Comment: I think the main problem is that you keep the accumulator until the end and then you add it. Kahan algorithm compensate every step. I'm not 100% sure, but I think this is what makes the difference. Have you tried the original algorithm instead of your modified one?

Comment: @Gilles-PhilippePaillé what alternative you mean exactly? by original, do you mean the one cited in Wikipedia?

Comment: The algorithms listed in wikipedia as "enhancements" seem to be nonsensical, only the original KahanSum makes sense there...

Comment: @MAero2020 Yes, the original algorithm. Not the modified versions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did a quick test, using an implementation of Kahan summation I wrote some time ago, and compared it to yours:

```cpp
#include <cfloat>
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <numeric>
#include <random>
#include <vector>

namespace Kahan {
template <class InIt>
typename std::iterator_traits<InIt>::value_type accumulate(InIt begin, InIt end) {
    typedef typename std::iterator_traits<InIt>::value_type real;
    real sum = real();
    real running_error = real();

    for ( ; begin != end; ++begin) {
        real difference = *begin - running_error;
        real temp = sum + difference;
        running_error = (temp - sum) - difference;
        sum = temp;
    }
    return sum;
}
}

using namespace std;
float KahanAlgorithm(const vector<float> &myarray){
    float sum{0.0f};
    float ac{0.0f};

    for(unsigned int i=0; i<myarray.size();i++){
        float temp{sum+myarray[i]};
        if(sum>=myarray[i]){
            ac=ac+(sum-temp)+myarray[i];
        }
        else{
            ac=ac+(myarray[i]-temp)+sum;
        }
        sum=temp;
    }

    return sum+ac;
}
int main() {

    int n=100000000;
    random_device r;
    default_random_engine g(r());
    uniform_real_distribution<float> d(0.f, nextafter(1.f, DBL_MAX));

    vector<float> a(n);
    vector<double> b(n);

    for(auto i=0;i<n;i++){
        a[i]=d(g);
        b[i]=static_cast<double> (a[i]);

    }

    double exact_sum;
    float kahan_sum;

    exact_sum=accumulate(b.begin(),b.end(),0.0);
    cout<<"exact "<<exact_sum<<endl;
    kahan_sum=KahanAlgorithm(a);
    cout<<" Kahan sum "<<kahan_sum<<endl;
    float jerry = Kahan::accumulate(a.begin(), a.end());
    cout << "Jerry's implementation of Kahan: " << jerry << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Sample result:

```
exact 4.99944e+07
 Kahan sum 3.35544e+07
Jerry's implementation of Kahan: 4.99944e+07
```

Comment: what do you mean by `real`? I do not understand the type of sum and running error

Comment: @MAero2020: `typedef typename std::iterator_traits<InIt>::value_type real;` (if I were writing this today, I'd probably use a `using` instead of a `typedef`, which would probably make that easier to spot). Anyway, it deduces `real` as whatever type the iterator refers to, so here I've passed it `a.begin()`/`a.end()`, and `a` is a `vector<float>`, so `real == float`. I did it this way to be generic, so it could work on a `vector<double>` just as well as a `vector<float>`.

Comment: The irony is why the result of your implementation has become so exact? it must have some error in the order of 1 to 10

Comment: @MAero2020: If you print the result out to *full* precision, you'll typically see a *little* difference between my implementation of Kahan summation, and the double-precision one (but with proper implementation, we expect Kahan to produce a result *very* close to the accuracy of a naive summation with double the precision).